# angularjs url together with django framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, d3.js

I have a small issue with angular's ng-click() and redirecting to new page. Here is the problem:

In my html I have small d3 app with an attribute:

```
.attr("ng-click", "go(" + "'" + "{% url 'home' %}" + "'" + ")")
```

in my js document I have:

```
$scope.go = function(link) {
    $location.path(link);
};
```

My base url is sth like:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/username/test/
```

Now when I click on the d3 element I get the following:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/username/test/#home/
```

However I wish to have:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/home/
```

Have You got any tips to fix that? I tried also with $location.hash(...) and no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service:

```
.attr("ng-click", "$window.location.href = '{% url 'home' %}'")
```

[`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) is for when need to stay inside the same single page.